# What is the expected behaviour when trying to read from wrong ADC channel (i2c protocol)

Tags: python, i2c, adc

I am trying to read a value from a light sensor using an i2c protocol. It goes into my ADC through the channel 1 (that's what's written).
I read the data like this:

```
data = i2cbus.read_i2c_block_data(address, register, 2)
```

I would expect to get three different results:

- if the channel exists and is in use, I would get a coherent value
- if the channel exists and is not being used, I would get a (low?) value due to static noise.
- if the channel does not exist, I would get an error.

However I get: (my ADC has 4 channels, only channel 1 is being used)

- channels 1 and 2: data is [0, 18]
- channel 3: data is [0, 19]
- channels 4 to infinity: data is [111, 21]

Can someone explain to me what is happening, and what would be considered normal?

thanks!

Comment: Not *low* but related to the *Vref*. Nevertheless it's **highly** recommended to ground unused ADC inputs to avoid all possible damages (yes, antennas in microelectronics are not a good thing when it's not on purspose).

Comment: It's pity you haven't pointed out which kernel version and what type of ADC you are using. For some of them there are drivers in the Linux kernel and working with them is much easier than reinventing a wheel in Python.

Comment: The behavior will depend on the type of ADC used. What ADC do you have?

Comment: I am using an MCP3428.
My linux version is the raspberry pi OS which I believe is a version of debian...?